# Storing pointers to structs in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers

**Task:** I want to create a `NSMutableArray` which would hold pointers to `CGPoint` structures, and then use these pointers in other objects (custom-made, inherited from `NSObject`) and arrays, so that when I change actual values behind the pointers in the `NSMutableArray`, it would be seen from everywhere. I don't like the idea of encapsulating it in `NSValue` since that would break the functionality as I want it.

**Some code now:**

```
// Triangle.h

@interface Triangle : NSObject
{
    CGPoint *p1;
    CGPoint *p2;
    CGPoint *p3;
}

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint *p1;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint *p2;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint *p3;

@end
// @synthesize in Triangle.m for p1, p2, p3


// somewhere in MyCustomView.m

CGFloat *MRatio = 3.0f; // some values
CGFloat *NRatio = 5.0f; // doesn't matter

rawPoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (NSInteger j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        CGPoint p = CGPointMake(j * MRatio, i * NRatio);
        [rawPoints addObject:(__bridge id)&p]; // *** crashes here
    }
}


Triangle *t = [[Triangle alloc] init];
t.p1 = (__bridge CGPoint *)([rawPoints objectAtIndex:0]);

NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(*t.p1)); // original value

CGPoint *pp1 = (__bridge CGPoint *)([rawPoints objectAtIndex:0]);
*pp1 = CGPointMake(-1.0f, -1.0f);

NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(*t.p1)); // changed value
```

**Problem:**
I thought the code this way is correct, with all the bridges and stuff, but it crashes on the inserting to rawPoints, not even getting to the end. Too sad.

**Question:**
Can someone help me understand what I did wrong, and help me make it right so it works in the way I described, perhaps using a different objects or methods?

Thanks!

Comment: bridge doesn't magically convert `CGPoint *` to a valid ObjC object. you were trying to fool the compiler so it compile your code. but it won't make your code work.

Comment: Since all "valid ObjC objects" are pointers, I thought that'd do the trick. That's how we learn, I guess :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a far more fundamental problem than storing pointers to structs...

A struct is a value type and within a function/method that means it is allocated automatically  with a limited lifetime. In your code:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (NSInteger j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        CGPoint p = CGPointMake(j * MRatio, i * NRatio);
        [rawPoints addObject:(__bridge id)&p]; // *** crashes here
    }
}
```

The lifetime of `p` is from its point of creation to the end of the current (inner) loop iteration. The `&p` you are trying to store is invalid immediately after you (fail in this case) to store it.

You either need to store your points as *values*, or if you want to mutate them store them in dynamic memory. There are various ways to do this but the simplest for you might be to just create a simple wrapper class which contains the `CGPoint`:

```
@interface CGPointWrapper

@property CGPoint point;

@end

@implementation CGPointWrapper
// nothing to do
@end
```

**Note**: if you create a `CGPoint` *property*, as above, setting elements of the structure using this property does **not** alter the value stored in the class - due to value semantics. However you can set the whole struct value to a new `CGPoint` value. If you wish to set elements of the structure you will need to add methods to do that.

HTH

Comment: This sounds very promising! Going to try it asap, thanks for the additional info, explanation and code example, I appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't allowed to store non-object pointers in the usual collection classes.  [According to the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000034-SW6), there are specialty collection classes ([`NSPointerArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSPointerArray_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html), [`NSMapTable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSMapTable_class/Reference/NSMapTable.html), and [`NSHashTable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSHashTable_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)) to handle collections of arbitrary pointers.

Comment: There is also an object -- I forget the name -- for storing non-object values.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yep, `NSValue` (which was specifically mentioned as not being desired in the question) can be used to wrap `CGPoint` and I think pretty much any arbitrary pointer in order to put it into one of the usual collection classes.  (Although it's easier to use `NSValue` to wrap `CGPoint` and the like on OSX than on iOS because the functionality provided by `NSValue` is better...)

Comment: That might help with some part of my problem, but as @CRD stated in his answer, the lifetime of the structures is the real problem needed to be solved, and I agree to that after consideration. Thanks for the info though! I'm sure I'll use it very soon :)

Comment: This is the correct answer, although it would be more generous to also write a sample few lines to demonstrate the use of NSHashTable for storing those CGPoint structs.